# Use visual studio default include folder to add library header files

Tags: c, visual-studio

I am using [libsodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium) in a c project using visual studio with the normal way of including headers and lib file with "Additional Headers Directories" and "Additional Library Directories".

What I want to ask if it is possible to add the headers to

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include"

and the .lib file to

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib"

so that it is included by default in any project I use ? and if it would be considered bad practice ?

Thanks

Comment: It's better to have project-specific dependencies in the project-specific locations. You might want to reinstall you VC, for example, and then it will mess with the default libraries. Or you might want to compile your project on a different machine, and forget about libraries.

Comment: As @EugeneSh. says, it's better to use project specific libraries.  I find it's easy enough using this alternative method to what you have done:  within `stdafx.h` you just `#include libsodium.h` followed by `#pragma comment(lib, "\path\to\libsodium.lib")`.